# Rails requests in all apartment subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, apartment-gem

I have an application with subdomain per organization. A user can be part of more than one organization. I use apartment to create tenants.

How can I check if a user is in more than one subdomain after he logs in?

Answer (score 0):

If the user object after logging in is `current_user`,

```
if 1 < current_user.organization.count
```